# Does a NSManagedObjectContext Automatically Delete Objects

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am using Core Data to store a `User` entity which has a to many relationship to another entity (`ScheduleDay`). Every time I sync I use this line to reset the Ordered Set:

```
self.user.scheduleDays = [NSOrderedSet orderedSet];
```

My question is are the old days being deleted, or is there a better way to make sure I delete the old days as to not clutter up the `NSManagedObjectContext` or save too much unnecessary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this will not automatically delete these objects.

You have to manually delete them yourself prior to setting the `scheduleDays` to a new set.

To delete all the `scheduleDays` entities, you could do this for example:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.user.managedObjectContext;

for (NSManagedObject *object in self.user.scheduleDays)
{
    [context delete:object];
}

self.user.scheduleDays = [NSOrderedSet orderedSet];

NSError *error;
[context save:&error];

if (error)
{
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: Will this cause any long term effects? Will the amount of data saved just increase forever?

Comment: Long term effects would be that your underlying data store (most commonly, underlying `SQL` database) managed by Core Data will have more and more objects added into it that aren't needed. It's best to actually just delete these, set the `scheduleDays` to new set, and go about your business. :D

Comment: One quick last question. Do you know an effective way to delete all objects of a certain Entity?

Comment: You can ommit `self.user.scheduleDays = [NSOrderedSet orderedSet];` because your relationship delete rule will take care of that. It is set to "Nullify" by default.

Comment: @JohnEstropia is correct. Assuming you have your relationship delete rule from each `scheduleDay` object to the `user` object set to `nullify`, you can omit `self.user.scheduleDays = [NSOrderedSet orderedSet];`

Comment: @JRG-Developer I now have another problem to solve. Lets say that maybe I have already released this app with this data problem. This means users have thousands of unused `ScheduleDays` saved. What would be the best way to delete all of these unused `NSManagedObjects`? Is there a way to delete all of them on a CoreData migration because that would be ideal.